# What products are available that attach to existing fitness machines (weights/treadmills/cardio etc) to track usage?

Tags: gym, exercise-equipment, programs, tracking

We are trying to find an off the shelf system that we can attach to existing fitness machines in a gym that tracks machine usage on a user basis. So the idea would be to attach them to all machines and provide all users with a login of some form (PIN number/RF tag etc) and then it can automatically track their usage and ideally provide real time feedback as relevant.

I understand there are quite a few companies who make their own fitness machines where this is possible. However we need to retrofit this to existing machines so wanted to see if anyone knew of any companies that offer this?

The only one we can currently find it FitLinxx (http://www.fitlinxx.net/fitlinxx-professional-overview.htm), does anyone know of any others?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I know old clothes are a popular item to hang on treadmills to track inactivity with real time feedback in amount of dust accumulated. As for activity, I sadly am unaware third party tools that meet this need. If possible, I would suggest contacting gym resellers/wholesellers directly to see if they have such a product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about tracking usage on a machine, not using the machine in a fitness program.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of any other retro fitters, but technically a bespoke system would be a trivial exercise; wondering if you've considered an alternative that may be cheaper, be less hassle to run, especially if you have no desire to capture the results from any trip computers your equipment currently carries, or a desire to issue RFID keys to your clients, and inform them of the details of their workouts. All you'd need to do is persuade your clients to have their [phones](http://www.nfcworld.com/nfc-phones-list/) with them during their visits, and to touch in / out on each bit of equipment to record a workout. Your capital outlay would be a roll of passive [NFC tags](http://www.amazon.co.uk/NFC-Tags-NTAG203-Clear-Stickers/dp/B00M5PC0FG/ref=pd_sim_sbs_office_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=0KA138835TZXXMH3PHSC), simply stick one on each bit of equipment, and then go find a school kid to customise a pair of the sample Android and iPhone NFC app's, to simply associate each tag with a specific bit of equipment, and add a bit of branding. Could even add a few very simple formula to calculate calories burnt on each bit of kit / total calories per visit....

Also on the bespoke front you could mount an [RFID reader](http://www.amazon.co.uk/FACILLA-Contactless-Proximity-Sensor-Electronics/dp/B00GS18VFQ/ref=pd_sim_office_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=18FERGMKYZMWENCEJ0EK) on each piece of equipment, have a supply of [RFID tags](http://www.amazon.co.uk/125kHz-Proximity-Keyfobs-Plastic-Resist/dp/B00BIYNA72/ref=pd_bxgy_ce_text_z) and for the slightly geekier bit, find somewhere to stash / something like a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Pi-Motherboard-Starter-Kit/dp/B00LU2FDG8/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1424988705&sr=1-1-spell&keywords=raspberry%20pie%20kit) around each bit of kit. Would need power and be able to reach the USB connector on the reader and any USB / serial interface on the bit of gym equipment. There are numerous example RFID projects for the PI, so wouldn't take long for an average school kid to cobble together a few routines to capture touch in's / out's on a bit of kit, along with any details a trip computer may offer, and to write the details back to a central server. But you'd need to develop a back end system to aggregate and present the data to your staff, to present to the clients, along with creating a system to issue tags to your clients.